# How to position nested Tbox in top right?

Tags: latex, tikz

How to position the smaller nested box, so it appeared in the top right corner (see image below)?
[image]

Here is my current, wrong implementation:

```
\newcommand\TBox[3][]{%
  \tikz\node[draw,ultra thick,text width=#2,align=left,#1] {#3};}

\TBox{14cm}{%
  \TBox{10cm}{xxx \vspace{9cm}} \TBox{3cm} \\ 
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide the smallest document to reproduce it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to place all your boxes in a single `tikzpicture`, because right now you are nesting them which is in general not a good idea.

To come back to your original question, you can use `baseline=(current bounding box.north)` to top align the boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\TBox[3][]{%
  \tikz\node[draw,ultra thick,text width=#2,align=left,#1,baseline=(current bounding box.north)] {#3};}

\begin{document}

\TBox{14cm}{%
  \TBox{10cm}{xxx \vspace{9cm}} \TBox{3cm} \\ 
  }

\end{document}
```

[image]